# Перенаправление HTTP/HTTPS траффика с эмулятора андроид на прокси сервер

Tags: android, c#, proxy, эмулятор

Пробовал различными готовыми проксификаторами - безрезультатно. Знаю что с помощью Fiddler можно снифать трафик с эмулятора, знаю что есть FiddlerCore, но не знаю получится ли с его помощью перенаправить трафик на прокси-сервер. Может кто-то работал уже с этим, или есть другие способы это осуществить?

Answer (score 1):

Запускаете на ПК сниффер, который работает, как прокси (Например, [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)), настраиваете на телефоне прокси сервер с IP своего компа и портом сниффера, и сниффите весь трафик на компе. Я делаю именно так.

Comment: Я тоже делаю так, но с помощью Fiddler-a. Но дело в том, что я то не хочу сниффать трафик, я хочу его "перенаправить" на прокси-сервер

Comment: @ИльяМУЛЛАНУРОВ, тогда просто настройте прокси сервер в настройках WIFI. Или вы хотите, чтобы трафик только вашего приложения шел через прокси?

Comment: не работает, прокси приватные

Comment: @ИльяМУЛЛАНУРОВ, что значит *приватные*? с авторизацией?

Comment: да, с авторизацией

Comment: @ИльяМУЛЛАНУРОВ, не вижу проблемы - вы можете ввести в настройках прокси данные для авторизации.